# multicolumn with columns spanning several pages

Tags: multicol

I would like to have an abstract and the translation of that abstract at the beginning of my document, in such a way, that I have two columns, e.g. the left one with the translation (let's say german) and the second column with the original abstract. If the text is exceeding the length of the left column, then the multicol environment will continue in the second/right column. What if I want to have the translation in the left column, spanning over several pages if necessary, and the original text in the second column, also spanning over several pages. I've also tried the longtable environment, but this results in strange line  and paragraph spacings, and it does not look real good.

Please, any held is appreciated!
Regards, George

Here some minimal example...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Kurzdarstellung}
Hier der deutsche Text. \lipsum
\columnbreak
\section*{Abstract}
Here the english text. \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://ctan.org/topic/crit-ed and http://ctan.org/topic/parallel for a range of options.

Comment: You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `paracol` package instead of `multicol`.

The environment corresponding to `multicols` is `paracol` and the command corresponding to `\columnbreak` is `\switchcolumn`, but the result is:

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just for the example
\usepackage[latin]{babel} %just for the example

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{Kurzdarstellung}
Hier der deutsche Text. \lipsum
\switchcolumn
\section*{Abstract}
Here the english text. \lipsum
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Another option is to use the `parcolumns` package.

This is an example which gives, more or less, the same result as the above one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just for the example
\usepackage[latin]{babel} %just for the example

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{%
\section*{Kurzdarstellung}
Hier der deutsche Text. \lipsum
}
\colchunk[2]{%
\section*{Abstract}
Here the english text. \lipsum
}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the relatively new `paracol` package for this:

[image: Sample top]

...

[image: Sample middle]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{Kurzdarstellung}
\Blindtext
\switchcolumn
\otherlanguage{english}
\section*{Abstract}
\Blindtext
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```